# Como posso baixar PDF de uma pagina web de forma automática

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, http

Existe alguma maneira de baixar um PDF *embed* em uma página web? Atualmente estou utilizando o controle `WebBrowser.ShowSaveAsDialog()` (Salvar Como) mas preciso fazer sem isso, de forma automática utilizando C# Windows Forms

Meu código:

```
private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    browserPlus1.Navigate("https://www3.webiss.com.br/aracajuse/FormRelNFSe.aspx?tipo=emitirrelatorio&MostrarRel=false&idRec=verificarnfse&IdNotaEletronica=17926183&Expiration=10032016055357&Verificador=566");
    browserPlus1.ShowSaveAsDialog();

}
```

Só que no meu caso não possui a extensão no endereço da URL

Comment: O que você chama de "PDF embebed"? Tente mostrar melhor sua situação.

Comment: Pdf embed é um arquivo pdf que abre no navegador e não possui a extensão pdf,geralmente em paginas aspx, infelizmente não posso postar o link pois parece que não é permitido

Comment: Mostre um exemplo. Mostre o que fez.

Comment: esta no corpo da abertura dessa Thread como estou fazendo:
"WebBrowser.ShowSaveAsDialog();"

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1911/101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui da forma abaixo utilizando o DDL IMPORT

```
 /// <summary>
    /// The URLMON library contains this function, URLDownloadToFile, which is a way
    /// to download files without user prompts.  The ExecWB( _SAVEAS ) function always
    /// prompts the user, even if _DONTPROMPTUSER parameter is specified, for "internet
    /// security reasons".  This function gets around those reasons.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pCaller">Pointer to caller object (AX).</param>
    /// <param name="szURL">String of the URL.</param>
    /// <param name="szFileName">String of the destination filename/path.</param>
    /// <param name="dwReserved">[reserved].</param>
    /// <param name="lpfnCB">A callback function to monitor progress or abort.</param>
    /// <returns>0 for okay.</returns>
    [DllImport("urlmon.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, PreserveSig = false)]
    private static extern void URLDownloadToFile(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object pCaller,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string szURL,
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string szFileName,
        Int32 dwReserved,
        IntPtr lpfnCB);

URLDownloadToFile(null, cidade_municipio + @"FormRelNFSe.aspx?tipo=emitirrelatorio&MostrarRel=false&idRec=verificarnfse&IdNotaEletronica=" + nfs + "&Expiration=23032015031453&Verificador=" + j, txtSalvar.Text +"\\"+nfs.ToString() + "_" + j.ToString() + ".pdf", 0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Answer (score 2):

Normalmente o mais fácil a fazer neste caso é baixar o arquivo com o componente apropriado:

```
using (var client = new System.Net.WebClient()) {
    client.DownloadFile("http://www.dominio.com.br/arquivo/1295889", "arquivo.pdf");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/IO/WebClient.cs).

[Documentação do método](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_WebClient_DownloadFile_System_String_System_String_).

Comment: Já usei assim e não funciona ele baixa o html,já usei MemoryStream, Webcliente e nenhum dos dois surtiram efeito

Comment: Então o exemplo que você colocou não é a forma que você está usando. Se você tentou de outras formas, deve colocar na pergunta. Coloque lá o que realmente você fez. Mostre seu código. Mostre realmente a situação do arquivo.

Comment: Já coloquei explicito o código e a url que uso para teste

Comment: Só lembrando se for testar tem que marcar Acesso Publico e colocar o captcha

Comment: De acordo com comentários na outra resposta há um CAPTCHA a ser preenchido antes do download. Aí não tem jeito, já que o CAPTCHA é usado justamente para evitar que um programa baixe o conteúdo do PDF.

Comment: @Renan parece ser isto mesmo, pergunta XY.

Comment: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/499/o-que-%C3%A9-o-problema-xy

Answer (score 0):

Só copie e cole o código abaixo e veja se ajuda!

```
WebClient webclient = new WebClient();
webclient.DownloadFile(url_link, "C:meudocumentoem.pdf");
```

Answer (score -2):

Conforme [resposta do Shadow Wizard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4097167/825789), do StackOverflow em inglês, partindo do princípio de que o servidor envia o cabeçalho *content-disposition*:

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    using (Stream rawStream = client.OpenRead(url))
    {
        string fileName = string.Empty;
        string contentDisposition = client.ResponseHeaders["content-disposition"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contentDisposition))
        {
            string lookFor = "filename=";
            int index = contentDisposition.IndexOf(lookFor, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
            if (index >= 0)
                fileName = contentDisposition.Substring(index + lookFor.Length);
        }
        if (fileName.Length > 0)
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(rawStream))
            {
                File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath(fileName), reader.ReadToEnd());
                reader.Close();
            }
        }
        rawStream.Close();
    }
}
```

Se houver necessidade de explicar a resposta aqui, comente que eu edito a minha.

Comment: Já usei esse dai também,não funcionou ele se comporta como o Webclient e so traz o html e não o pdf

Comment: Será que é devido ao captcha que tem antes?

Comment: Então há Captcha antes? Se houver, no momento do download, a página é a do Captcha ou é uma página em branco?

Comment: Pelo que eu reparei, realmente há Captcha, ai fica MUITO mais complexa a situação.

Comment: A pagina que vem é a do captcha mesmo, tem alguma maneira de manipular o WebBrowser.ShowSaveAsDialog() para poder escolher um local ou deixar automatico?

Comment: Então não há possibilidade, o Captcha foi feito para este fim.

Comment: Bom pessoal agradeço a todos, mais infelizmente devido ao captcha que tenho de acessar antes não há a possibilidade de se automatizar sem utilizar o WebBrowser.ShowSaveAsDialog().